# What does getRobotFootprint() refer?

Tags: ros, turtlebot, ros-hydro, footprint

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a function footprintCost() in carrot_planner.cpp

```
  double CarrotPlanner::footprintCost(double x_i, double y_i, double theta_i){
    if(!initialized_){
      ROS_ERROR("The planner has not been initialized, please call initialize() to use the planner");
      return -1.0;
    }
    std::vector footprint = costmap_ros_->getRobotFootprint();
    //if we have no footprint... do nothing
    if(footprint.size() footprintCost(x_i, y_i, theta_i, footprint);
    return footprint_cost;
  }
```

The thing I want to know is a part of `footprint.size()`. I think that costmap_common_params.yaml has footprint like this vector.

```
footprint: [[0.18, 0.18],[0.18, -0.18],[-0.18,-0.18],[-0.18,0.18]]
```

So, I have to set above footprint instead of robot_radius. But global_planner doesn't need the footprint.
 Am I correct?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/175181/what-does-getrobotfootprint()-refer?/) by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 894 on 2014-06-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-06-30**:
Does the footprint mean x, y, theta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This answer is written on here( http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/costmap_2d/html/classcostmap__2d_1_1Costmap2DROS.html#add1c9e06ffbae7fecc956c3c377f869e ).
Return the current footprint of the robot as a vector of points.This version of the footprint is padded by the footprint_padding_ distance, set in the rosparam "footprint_padding".The footprint initially comes from the rosparam "footprint" but can be overwritten by dynamic reconfigure or by messages received on the "footprint" topic.

---

Originally posted by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) with karma: 894 on 2014-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) on 2015-06-15**:
hello,Ken, in my  turtlebot_navigation/costmap_common_params.yaml,footprint was defined by robot_radius: 0.18,do you know how many points  it used to define the circle shape ?